# Oracle Query compare 2 columns that both have dates and only display the record if column a less than column b

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have Oracle data in which I only want to retrieve the records that have a date from a column that is greater than the date of another column date.

```
select o.outage_k,o.work_fldr_k,o.crt_d, o.closed_d,o.etr_d from outage o
```

[image]

I was wondering if I want to filter out date in the SELECT or in the WHERE clause?

So a Case Statement?

In the the query I show in the screenshot I would NOT want to return that records BECAUSE  ETR_D is greater than Closed_D

So what I want is to return all records in where CLOSED_D > ETR_D

Probably cannot use greater than > symbol as well for date compare

Comment: If you are comparing columns within the same row then use `WHERE` clause.  What is the data type for `CLOSED_D` and for `ETR_D`?

Comment: It is a data type of  DATE  in Oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just compare the dates in WHERE clause:

```
WHERE CLOSED_D > ETR_D
```

Did something not work when you tried that?

Comment: That works I just didn't think it was going to be so simple ( I am used to sql server and I thought I might have to use some date functions